# Какие есть нормальные конвертеры js html to pdf с кириллицей?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Я думал, что будет плохо, но не на столько.

jsPDF - крайне странная, с отвратительной документацией, вещь, которую мне так и не удалось настроить. Там либо HTML, либо кириллица. Либо блин дудочка, либо кувшинчик. Про scale (масштаб) - который я так и не нашел - вообще молчу.

mPDF - основанная на jsPDF, но текст становится картинкой, поэтому не подходит.

Мне не много надо:

- Кириллица (мне даже не принципиально, чтобы там был другой шрифт,
  пусть тот же Arial будет)
- Возможность выделения текста и в дальнейшем поиска по нему (чтобы на
  выходе не картинка)
- Возможность настраивать размер листа (мне нужен альбомный A4)
- Чтобы ширина моей страницы в 1200 px полностью занимала ширину листа
- Не разрывать строки таблицы (в css это называется page-break-inside:
  avoid;)

Comment: В [Интернетах пишут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352664/) что нужно явным образом установить документу шрифт, поддерживающий кириллицу.

Comment: Не уверен, полностью ли подойдёт, но попробуйте ещё [один из методов puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions), там под капотом вся мощность Chrome.